# Not able to see double quote which is present inside a string ,when loading it from csv into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe is skipping reading a double quote present inside a string when reading data from csv to pandas dataframe.

Suppose the data records present in my csv are as below.

```
name1|id|name2
"abc"|2|"def\"de" 
"abcd"|4|"def"de"
```

I'm using pipe symbol as separator while reading the csv file. Below is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Downloads\\synthetic-data.csv", sep="|").replace('"', '', regex=True)
```

print(df)
It is displaying as shown below:

```
    name1  id    name2
0     abc   2     def\de
1    abcd   4    defde
```

I don't understand here why the double quote(") is not present in the df and it is skipping. I'm expecting to have values as def"de and def"de in name2 column for row0 & row1 respectively. Please provide me your valuable inputs.

Comment: The typical way of escaping double quotes in the CSV format is the double them: `""` represents a single `"` inside a quoted string. I'm not sure what CSV dialect pandas uses by default and hence what escaping mechanism it expects…

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to define the `escapechar` in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
pd.read_csv('synthethic-data.csv', sep='|', escapechar='\\')
```

Output:

```
  name1  id    name2
0   abc   2  def"de 
1  abcd   4   defde"
```

Regarding the last line (`"abcd"|4|"def"de"`), the quoted part is actually `"def"`, so you can't directly keep the quote.

If you really need it, disable quoting and handle your quotes manually (this might fail if `|` are quoted):

```
pd.read_csv('synthethic-data.csv', sep='|', quoting=3) # quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
```

Output:

```
    name1  id       name2
0   "abc"   2  "def\"de" 
1  "abcd"   4    "def"de"
```

Comment: thank you. I tried using pd.read_csv('synthethic-data.csv', sep='|', escapechar='\\') . But now it is not displaying backslash ('\') in name2 for row0 and for row1 it is not displaying double quote(") inside the string.  Also for row1 got an " at the end of it, which is weird. My output looks like this:

    name1  id    name2
0   abc   2  def"de 
1  abcd   4   defde"

Comment: Can you rather edit the question, comments are not good to keep formatting

Comment: I tried with pd.read_csv('synthethic-data.csv', sep='|', quoting=3). this worked, but as you have mentioned, if I have another data record like "abcd"|5|"def\|de"  it's failing while executing the code. Can I also somehow read the string that uses pipe (|) operator enclosed in the double quoted strings ?

Comment: you can recognize the pipe escaped with ```\\```, but not by the double quotes if you disable quoting. Try: ```pd.read_csv('synthethic-data.csv', sep='|', escapechar='\\', quoting=3)```

Comment: if I use this pd.read_csv('synthethic-data.csv', sep='|', escapechar='\\', quoting=3) , it is now converting the string from "def\|de" to "def|de". Backslash symbol is being skipped, which is not the desired result. Also if another datarecord such as "xyz"|4|"ajc|fe" is also included to this, then the above code is failing with error such as -pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 4 .
So is there any way by which I can get the entire output string such as "def\|de" & "ajc|fe" for both of the records respectively?